# Aviary Editor Reduces the image quality

Tags: image-processing, aviary

We are using Aviary editor for image cropping in our website.the quality of the image is reduced after editing with aviary.is this the default behaviour or we can change any settings

Comment: Aviary is a commercial SDK. I suggest you just contact their support and ask them.

Comment: Please let us know what version of the Image Editor you are using. Note that Aviary has been replaced by [the Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior of Avairy.if we need good quality images means we need to go for premium plan

Answer (score 0):

Check these options

`Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
    .setData(uri) // input image source
    .withOutput(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/my-pic-name.jpg")) // output file destination
    .withOutputFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG) // output format
    .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp5) // output size
    .withOutputQuality(90) // output quality
    .build();`